# How to inspect outgoing HTTP requests of a single application?

Tags: networking

My application is sending HTTP requests to some server and I want to see the actual data that it is sending out. Some specifics I would like to see:

- Request method (GET/POST/PUT, etc.)
- Content-type
- Body

What is the best and simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: "method of request, content type, body and etc." Are you talking about HTTP-specific inspection? Is it HTTPS (secured) by any chance?

Comment: Yes, you're right but it's not sending by browser

Comment: Sorry, it's just HTTP requests

Comment: Okay, that's fine then. Is it just *one* or a small set of servers it's talking to? And no other applications are talking to those servers? If both yes, then the answer about Wireshark is what I would go for. Learn how it works. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Well, for all those tcpdump fans =)

**RUN ALL THESE COMMANDS AS ROOT !!!**

Obtain root in a terminal with

```
sudo -i
```

To capture the RAW packets ...

```
sudo tcpdump -i any -w /tmp/http.log &
```

This will capture all the raw packets, on all ports, on all interfaces and write them to a file, `/tmp/http.log`.

Run your application. It obviously helps if you do not run any other applications that use HTTP (web browsers).

Kill `tcpdump`

```
killall tcpdump
```

To read the log, use the `-A` flag and pipe the output to`less`:

```
tcpdump -A -r /tmp/http.log | less
```

The `-A` flag prints out the "payload" or ASCII text in the packets. This will send the output to `less`, you can page up and down. To exit `less`, type <kbd>Q</kbd>.

When I go to Google, I see (in the raw packets):

```
20:42:38.179759 IP ufbt.local.56852 > sea09s02-in-f3.1e100.net.www: Flags [P.], seq 1:587, ack 1, win 913, options [nop,nop,TS val 25523484 ecr 492333202], length 586
E..~.v@.@..q......!#...P.(.gS.c..............u..Xh.GET /generate_204 HTTP/1.1
Host: clients1.google.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) rekonq Safari/534.34
Referer: http://www.google.com/
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, x-gzip, x-deflate
Accept-Charset: utf-8,*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US, en-US; q=0.8, en; q=0.6
Cookie: PREF=ID=dd958d4544461998:FF=0:TM=1323842648:LM=1360205486:S=Fg_QCDsLMr4ZepIo; NID=67=OQJWjIDHG-B8r4EuM19F3g-nkaMcbvYwoY_CsOjzvYTOAxwqAos5kfzsk6Q14E70gIfJjHat8d8PuQIloB12BE-JuSHgsKHR2QSpgN12qSWoxeqhdcSQgzw5CHKtbR_a
```

`tcpdump` has a long set of options to refine data collection from specifying network interfaces to ports to source and destination IP addresses. It can NOT decrypt (so it will not work with HTTPS).

Once you know what you are interested in, you can use a number of options with `tcpdump` to record only the data of interest. The general strategy is to first record all the packets, review the raw data, and then capture only the packets of interest.

Some helpful flags (options):

```
-i Specify an interface
-i eth0

tcp port xx
tcp port 80

dst 1.2.3.4
specify a destination ip address
```

There is a learning curve, both to using `tcpdump` and learning how to analyze the data you collect. For further reading, I highly suggest [Daniel Miessler's `tcpdump` Primer with Examples](http://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/).

Comment: this does not capture anything on my Ubuntu 14.04. My laptop connects to the internet over a wifi router. Would that make a difference to the usage of tcpdump? When i kill it, it just says `0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
` But i did open a bunch of sites in the Chrome browser when tcpdump was monitoring.

Comment: ahh the linked article helped. `tcpdump -i any -w /tmp/http.log &` worked.

Answer (score 33):

First install `tcpflow` from Ubuntu official repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install tcpflow
```

Then run this command to inspect all HTTP requests on standard port:

```
sudo tcpflow -p -c port 80
```

Comment: and where to see the results? Thank you!

Comment: @Gediminas you can see the output in the terminal. Please note that HTTPS traffic is not shown. Try visiting an HTTP one such as http://www.httpvshttps.com/

Comment: Much more convenient than the tcpdump if you're just interested in seeing the requests and don't have to deal with all the TCP details (syn, ack...)

Answer (score 14):

I would suggest that you try [Wireshark [image: Install Wireshark]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wireshark)

Please note that Wireshark is quite advanced, and so may take a bit of getting used to. I have not used it for a few years, but it should still be perfect for what you are after - if not a bit too full of features.

Information about Wireshark and how to use it can be found at [the Wireshark homepage](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: This doesn't work for a single process. You'll get all traffic on the interface and you'll have to filter it by IP/protocol, etc. [wireshark - filter by process/pid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339691/wireshark-filter-by-process-pid)

Comment: yea, but it is easily accomplished with the wireshark interface.

Comment: I've tried wireshark before and it's too advanced for me, I'm  looking for another option

Comment: @megas - LOL, there is no easier program. Here is a (basic) tutorial - http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/packet-sniffing-basics

Comment: The other option is tcpdump. tcpdump is a command line tool, will easily do the job, but has a steeper learning curve. http://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/

Comment: Am actually incline towards tcpdump which could do this.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Post that as an answer with an example. I'm sure you'll get upvotes, but that OP will accept the GUI way (for this being easier).

Comment: @gertvdijk  - as you wish ;) Feel free to add to the basics

Comment: GUI is NOT always easier... I am very happy with the tcpdump answer, as I run a non-gui system for dev...

Answer (score 7):

Also possible with command, which gives tidy output, even for SSL:

```
sudo tcpdump dst port 80
```